# How long did the War of Five Kings last?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire, warfare, time

The Five Kings are:

- Robb Stark - The King of the North
- Stannis Baratheon - Robert's younger brother and legitimate heir
- Renly Baratheon - The youngest Baratheon who decided to proclaim himself king
- Joffrey Baratheon - Robert's "son" and apparent heir
- Balon Greyjoy - King of the Iron Islands

Based on book canon, the following fates have been met:

- > Robb - Dead, betrayed at the Red Wedding
- > Stannis - Alive, currently marching on Winterfell
- > Renly - Dead, murdered by smoke monster/Stannis
- > Joffery - Dead, murdered on his wedding day by a complex plot
- > Balon - Dead, "blown" off a bridge near his castle

All of these events happen at a different time at undefined intervals. Many battles are fought and much travel is done between some of the fates. **Is there any way to extrapolate in universe how long the war lasted?**

**OR, is the war still on going, since there is still a challenge (no matter now slim) for the Iron Throne?**

**And/or, if the war *is* over, which event decided that?**

Comment: Here's a timeline: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZsY3lcDDtTdBWp1Gx6mfkdtZT6-Gk0kdTGeSC_Dj7WM/

Comment: Is your premise that the war ended once four of the five kings were dead? Or that it ceased to be a war "of five kings" once one of them was gone? Or something else? From my point of view, the war is still on, as Stannis, the Greyjoys, and the Lannister-Baratheons are still pursuing their causes even without the aforementioned kings alive.

Comment: @recognizer I updated my question to address your point. However, with the Greyjoys, are they still actively pursuing the Iron Throne? Clearly, the Barathisters are because they currently sit on it...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**The [War of The Five Kings](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/War_of_the_Five_Kings#Factions) is still in progress.** As of [300AC](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/300_AC).

The war started in [298AC](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Years_after_Aegon%27s_Conquest#Year_298_After_the_Conquest) (two years ago). Although it is considered that the war is ongoing, the main part of the war is considered to have ended in [300AC](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Years_after_Aegon%27s_Conquest#Year_300_After_the_Conquest). There is no official ending of "Phase I", but it can be concluded that the first phase of the war ended with [The Purple Wedding](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Purple_Wedding). The second phase however is ongoing.

---

### The O.G. Five

As you know, the [original five belligerents were](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/67349/21267):

- **Robb Stark:**

  - [Wanted freedom for The North, Riverlands and The Iron Islands](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/70509/21267)
- **Stannis Baratheon:**

  - Felt the Throne was his by rights
- **Joffrey Baratheon:**

  - Felt the Throne was his by rights
- **Balon Greyjoy:**

  - Wanted freedom for the Iron Islands, so that they could rape, pillage and be total douche-bags in peace. Also wanted to annex The North, because, why not?
- **Renly Baratheon:**

  - For the lulz

The War of The Five Kings isn't necessarily defined by the number of kings, especially given that there were never actually exactly five kings at the same time<sup>1</sup>; it's defined by their "cause".

### Causes

**Stannis** hasn't given up, he very openly hasn't accepted defeat and hasn't made peace<sup>2</sup>. He's currently working his [magic](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/stannis-the-mannis) against the Boltons in The North, believing that he must first save the Kingdom to win The Crown.

- Threat: ongoing.

**The Greyjoys** haven't abandoned their cause either. Even after the death of Balon Greyjoy a new king is elected in a [Kingsmoot](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Kingsmoot#A_Feast_for_Crows). In fact, after electing a new [mental case](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Euron_Greyjoy) as king, they increase their scope slightly and decide to take over all of Westeros.

- Threat: impending

**Daenerys** is still threatening to return with her dragons and stuff. She's taken a small break to go on holidays with Drogon and hang out with [Khal Jhaqo](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Jhaqo#A_Dance_with_Dragons).

- Threat... Umm, we'll see.

Because of the above, the **Iron Throne** has had to continue their campaigns against the pretenders.

### Entering Phase II

No, really, we've [entered Phase II](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/War_of_the_Five_Kings#New_hostilities). There are "new hostilities" which have re-ignited the War of the Five Kings. The new belligerents are:

- **[Tommen Baratheon](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Tommen_Baratheon):**

  - The Boy King
  - Just wants everyone to get along and to play with his kittens
- **[Aegon VI Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon_Targaryen_(son_of_Rhaegar)):**

  - <strike>[The-Boy-Who-Lived](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter)</strike> The-Boy-Who-Washed-His-Hair
  - Believes The Throne is his by rights
  - Threat: very real.
- **[Stannis Baratheon](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Stannis_Baratheon):**

  - The King at The Wall
  - No, Stannis doesn't give up
- **[Euron Greyjoy](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Euron_Greyjoy)**:

  - [King of the Isles and the North](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/King_of_the_Isles_and_the_North)
  - Has it in his head that he can take Dany, her dragons, Westeros and whatever else he desires

Major events include:

- [**The Landing of The golden Company**](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Landing_of_the_Golden_Company)

  - [Aegon VI Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon_Targaryen_(son_of_Rhaegar)) has decided to de-crumple his face and stake his claim to the Iron Throne, landing his newly acquired [Golden Company](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Golden_Company) in Westeros.
- **[Assassination of Grand Maester Pycelle and Regent Kevan Lannister](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/A_Dance_with_Dragons-Epilogue)**

  - Varys decides to cause unrest and destabilise King Tommen and Queen Regent Cercei's rule by murdering Grand Maester Pycelle and Regent Kevan Lannister. Aftermath is yet to be released.

**When will it end?**
There are many factors playing upon this clash of kings (lol, get it?). The main one being that Winter is Coming, and it has been geared to be a long winter, most probably followed by a [Long Night](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Long_Night). The threat of the Others is real, and will cause all these idiots to wake up and face the threat! (hopefully)

---

<sup>1. [Renly died before Balon crowned himself](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/War_of_the_Five_Kings#Factions).

2. He even jailed and later burned his Hand and brother-in-law ([Alester Florent](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Alester_Florent)) for attempting to [make peace behind his back](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Alester_Florent#A_Storm_of_Swords).</sup>

Comment: And don't forget Dany herself, even though she had no active part in Westeros yet, but she also claims to be the rightful ruler and she doesn't know of Aegon (if I remember right).

Comment: If Dany gets to Westeros before any of those fellows die, we'll have five whole kings-and-queens alive and fighting at the same time, for once!

Comment: Just had a secondary thought... Didn't the Maesters give it the name originally in-universe? I am thinking that the combatants are not interchangeable.

Comment: Also, thinking on this again... Does Mance Rayder fit in here at all?

Comment: @Skooba Yes, it was Archmaester Benedict who pointed out the fact that there wasn't *technically* five kings at the same time (so in-universe).

Comment: @Skooba Also, in my opinion, Mance has no claim or influence on the conflicts for the Iron Throne, except that he side-tracked Stannis for a while.

Comment: "for the lulz" lol. But anyway, how exactly is Euron king of the North? Only by courtesy.